# What are the necessary files for Android SDK to develop a basic application?

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

My SDK folder size is arround 9 GO and i want to reduce this big size by deleting unused files when developing a simple application, so that i can copy the SDK folder in my students machines faster (we don't have internet connection to download SDK).

We will be using Genymotion as an emulator so that i have deleted the content of *system-images* folder and it didn't work and i still can't link android studio to the modified version of the sdk version.

Shortly, i want to know which files in SDK are necessary to develop in Android so that i can delete the rest of files and the size of SDK will be smaller.

Answer (score 2):

You can completely remove all the emulation and even older version of the emulation (system image). Just keep tools and the extras such as API's, play services, etc..

Good luck! Hopefully your student enjoy the course!

Edit: If you don't understand, a clear explanation (it should be easy to understand that if you used android studio for a while).

Go to the SDK manager, "launch standalone SDK manager", remove all system images and make sure you keep the stuff in the tools section and extra's. Its pretty simple if you used android studio.

Comment: Go to the SDK manager, "launch standalone SDK manager", remove all system images and make sure you keep the stuff in the tools section and extra's. Its pretty simple if you used android studio.

Answer (score 0):

These are the must have packages

Under `Tools` >

***Android SDK Tools***

***Android SDK Platform-tools***

***Android SDK Build-tools - (latest only)***

Atleast one ***SDK Platform***. Preferably of the latest API version. You'll need the SDK Platforms of both build-target and minimum API versions. If they are the same then that one alone. You might want to include ***Google APIs*** for these platforms as well)

Under `Extras` >

***Android Support Repository***

***Android Support Library***

***Googe USB Driver (unsure about this)***

Comment: I think documentation is not necessary.

Comment: Google usb driver is optional. Most phones also have their brand specific driver that comes with the pc software